# Regex to extract data to array

Tags: php, regex

Hope someone could help me because I'm not aware with regex.
I need to extract data included in a classic html page to a PHP array.
The HTML code is as below :

```
<html>
...some html code...
<div data-companycounter="9879" data-code="A" data-seatcounter="9783" class="">
...some html code...
<div data-companycounter="9879" data-code="B" data-seatcounter="9784" class="">
...some html code...
<div data-companycounter="11397" data-code="A" data-seatcounter="11509" class="">
...some html code...
</html>
```

And I would like to extract some data in an array like this :

```
$companycounter = [
    9879 => [
        'A' => 9783,
        'B' => 9784,
    ],
    11397 => [
        'A' => 11509
    ]
];
```

Hope it's clear enought. Thank for those who can help me

Comment: You might want to use an actual HTML parser for this job.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument

Comment: Yeah if you use `DOMDocument` class it would be easy to extract data. could you please check my answer out!

Answer (score 1):

```
function custom_parse_html($html)
{
    $company_counter = [];

    preg_match_all('/<div data-companycounter="(.*)" data-code="(.*)" data-seatcounter="(.*)" (.*)>/im', $html, $matches);

    foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $arr) {
        //  $matches[1][$key] => data-companycounter
        //  $matches[2][$key] => data-code
        //  $matches[3][$key] => data-seatcounter

        if (!empty($company_counter[$matches[1][$key]])) {
            $company_counter[$matches[2][$key]] = $matches[3][$key];
        } else {
            $company_counter[$matches[1][$key]] = [$matches[2][$key] => $matches[3][$key]];
        }
    }

    return $company_counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments Use [`HTML parser`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument) instead of regex it would be easy to extract data from *HTML*.
So just intial an object `$doc` from `DOMDocument` class.
get all divs by using method `getElementsByTagName`, Then iterate over them and take the desired company's information attributes, Set them to `$companycounter` array in a specific order.

```php
$html = 
'<div data-companycounter="9879" data-code="A" data-seatcounter="9783"/>
<div data-companycounter="9879" data-code="B" data-seatcounter="9784"/>
<div data-companycounter="11397" data-code="A" data-seatcounter="11509"/>';
```

```php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
$companycounter = [];
foreach ($divs as $div) {
  $counter = $div->attributes->item(0)->value; //data-companycounter
  $code = $div->attributes->item(1)->value; //data-code
  $seatcounter = $div->attributes->item(2)->value; //data-seatcounter
  $companycounter[$counter][$code] = $seatcounter;
}
```

```php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($companycounter);
```

**The Output* as expected:*

```
/*
Array
(
    [9879] => Array
        (
            [A] => 9783
            [B] => 9784
        )

    [11397] => Array
        (
            [A] => 11509
        )

)
```